# "Acess Denied" error from certain websites when connecting with VPN

Tags: vpn

I recently started using NordVPN to reroute my internet activity and noticed that certain websites are blocking the connection. Sometimes switching to a different server fixes the issue but sometimes it doesn't. How do they know that the request is coming from a VPN server and how can I get around the block without having to disable the VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NordVPN has a block of IP addresses that it owns. Any connection you do via NordVPN
will, for your target, seem to be coming from that block of addresses.

Some websites refuse connections from VPN providers, for safety reasons.

Some other websites ban IP addresses that were engaged in suspicious
activity.
As when connecting over the VPN your IP address is randomly chosen from
that block by NordVPN, you may have received one that is banned on the
website.
The solution in this case is to turn off the VPN for some time,
perhaps 15-30 minutes, then connect again, and with luck you might get
this time a non-banned address.

You may check your IP address using the website
[What Is My IP Address](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)
or any other such website.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much what I expected. Ironically,whatismyipaddress.com appears to be one of the sites that's blocking my ip address lol.